# How to get probability of data generated by generator using gan model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

We know that generative adversarial network(GAN) can generate data which is similar to real data. In general Generator needs a random variable z as input and generates a vector for representing data x. I don't know how to calculate the probability of P_G(x) when I have new data and want to know the probability of GAN generating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly compute the likelihood of data using GAN.

Original GAN paper uses parzen window based estimation of likelihood. You can generate data from GAN and use that data for estimating likelihood with whatever method you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to implement neural network(NN) model for maximum likelihood estimation. Data x generated from GAN inputs to NN and NN outputs a probability of p(x|theta), theta as parameters of NN. Theta is tuned continually until p(x|theta) approximates to 1. When I finish training process and input any x to NN, I found that NN always outputs 1. I don't know whether this process is right?

Comment: I am not sure of how that will work. What is your loss function exactly/?